# Install Google Chrome in Android 4.1.2

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have recently recovered my old tablet (Motorola Xoom Wifi). I am now on Android 4.1.2. The only important thing I am missing after recovery is Google Chrome.

I can see the application on the Google Play Store as [Chrome Browser - Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome), however the store indicates me "Your device isn't compatible with this version". I remember having some Google Chrome on the Xoom before recovery and I remember seeing the same message when I was offered to update Chrome recently (last few months). Is there some archive I could download older Chrome versions from?

Is there some way to check what exactly does the new Chrome require my tablet does not have?

The only browser I have available now is the "Browser", and while it works, I would definitely prefer using Chrome.

Comment: See related answer http://android.stackexchange.com/a/134597/131553

Comment: do you have synced your google account?

Comment: @RahulGopi Yes, I did.

Comment: I think this is mostlyI was looking for - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148367/how-can-i-securely-install-an-older-version-of-chrome-on-a-device-that-wont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have Chrome `54.0.2 840.68`, which is a prior version to what is available on the play store
- Min API level is 21 and targetted is 25, which corresponds to Android 5.0 and 7.1.1 as can be seen [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)
- API level was read using [manifest viewer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)
- Incompatibility warning is being shown as your Android version is not supported. Options you have and associated risks are explained in the accepted answer here [Chrome Browser is not supported on this device (Samsung GT-P7500)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/134532/131553). That leaves you with choices of:

  1. Upgrading your Android version
  2. Accepting security risk of using earlier version downloaded from a secure site as [commented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167188/install-google-chrome-for-old-tablet-phone/167193#comment214002_167188)
  3. Using a different browser

Comment: What is a bit confusing to me is even the quite recent [55 version](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-55-0-2883-91-release/) is listed as "Min: Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean, API 16)" . Is the manifest viewer info more reliable?

Comment: I see your point and I really don't have an answer. On one hand the site is reputed and on the other the app is only showing what's there

Comment: App shows min and targetted sdk levels . SDK kernels are same as API - *Despite its name, this element is used to specify the API Level, not the version number of the SDK (software development kit) or Android platform* as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)

Comment: When I have tried to install that particular 55 version, it does not work correctly for me. It  installs, starts, but crashes (disappears silently) once I start typing URL. Version 42 works fine. I did not try any versions in between yet.

Comment: Your link shows device chipset as also a factor - *arm / x86* etc

Comment: Version 42 is compatible with 4.0 , so  probably working fine

Comment: For the record: [version 49](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-49-0-2623-105-release/) seems to work fine so far.

Comment: I am now on the 4.4.4 Kitkat on the same device (rooted, Omnirom) and I see the same behaviour: recent build (starting with 50) tells me "Unfortunately, Chrome has stopped", last build which works is version 49 again. Could I check somehow what exactly is my tablet missing, as recent Chrome should supporting 4.1?

Comment: @Suma:: sorry, don't know, that could be another Q, linking this Q as background

Answer (score 1):

Google play store shows many apps as incompatible although they might work just fine. If you are okay with downloading third party applications, you can download the .apk file for Google chrome from http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/chrome-browser-apk-latest-version-download/

Inform me if you are unable to install the application after downloading it.

Comment: I have already tried the Beta / Dev Chrome, as those are shown to me by the Play Store. None of them works for me.

Comment: It means that the latest version of chrome browser can't run on your device

Comment: What you can do is install an older version from a third party

Comment: But it is quite risky to use an outdated browser as you can be infected by malware.