# Chrome INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS but I am certain it doesn't

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Hi all I am trying to side load a chrome apk via ADB but it is giving me the INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS error. I have verified via exhaustive searches of the packages and even the root that no file/apk/package exists that even has the word chrome in its title anywhere. Play Store also confirmed it is not installed. It will download the file but gives "already installed" error when it tried to load it.  Cleared all caches/data and same.  Also tried direct downloading the apk and installing that way but it just crashes.

The only thing I can think of is there is some other "flag" or registry somewhere that is telling it that it is still installed when it isn't?  Where might that be? Or a hidden file perhaps?

FYI this is Android 4.4.2 older machine but needed.

Thanks

Comment: That apk you are trying to install needs to be compatible with your Android version. New version of Chrome will not install on old Android version. See this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/167193/131553

Comment: Above may / may not be the reason for the error IDK but p pointing out another aspect

Comment: have you tried `adb install -r` (for "re-install")? That usually helps with this error.

Comment: thanks, yes I am installing a significantly older version which I believe is compatible.

Comment: yes thanks -r didn't work either.  same failure already exists.  it loads the apk into a temp folder just fine but the install itself fails.  Chrome version 39.  i have scrubbed the app and system and all folders for any reference to com.android.chrome or anything with the string "chrome" in it and nothing. I do have link2SD installed does this affect installation of apps any?

Comment: also in /data/app there were 6 vmdlxxxxx.tmp files which I deleted still didn't work.  checked all other apps folders but nothing related to chrome